# How to write contents outside of table

Tags: css

I want to create a  table in my wordpress website. i want to place the table in the right side.  The problem is, if i want to write contents outsides like  to  left side of the table then how will i do it.  Can you please give me an example?

I am beginner in css so plz  forgive me for the writing style.

I want to make a style for a website like (the pic i have attached). Can you Please help me that how can I write freely in the left side of the table?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute`:

```
#navbar {
    position: absolute; left: 0;
    width: 20%;
}

#content {
    position: absolute; right: 0; /*Presuming this is the table*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the display property of css, this is mainly used for aligning content on webpages.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

You mean a table inside the content div?

```
#content {
  margin-left:20%;
}
#navbar {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
}    
.table-wrapper {
   display:inline-block;
}

<div id="layout">
  <div id="header">Top Header</div>
  <div id="navbar">Navigation</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <table><tr><td>table 1</td></tr></table>            
        </div>
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <table><tr><td>table 2</td></tr></table>            
        </div>
    </div>
  <div id="footer">Bottom Footer</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KhH42/1/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#wrapper {
    border:solid 2px #000;
    margin:20px;
}
#wrapper div[class*="col-"]{
    float:left;
}    
.col-1 { width:30%; background:#eee; }
.col-2 { width:30%; background:#e2e2e2; }
.col-3 { width:40%; background:#ccc; }    
#wrapper:after { content:""; clear:both; display:block; }

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col-1">
        <p>col 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <p>col 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    my table
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3LUqg/